# SQL - delete duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how I can delete duplicate rows from my database but keep one:

```
|---------------------------|
| id   titleid     version  |
|---------------------------|
| 1   TEST1        1.60     | <--- keep
| 2   TEST1        1.60     | <--- delete
| 3   TEST1        1.60     | <--- delete
| 4   TEST1        1.60     | <--- delete
| 5   TEST55       1.55     | <--- not selected
| 6   TEST88       1.85     | <--- not selected
| 7   TEST56       1.60     | <--- keep
| 8   TEST56       1.60     | <--- delete
|---------------------------|
```

I've been able to figure out how to select the rows that have duplicate rows:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM patch a
JOIN (
    SELECT titleid, version, COUNT(*)
    FROM patch
    GROUP BY titleid, version
    HAVING count(*) > 1
) b 
ON a.titleid = b.titleid
AND a.version = b.version 
ORDER BY a.version
```

How can I modify this query so it deletes the duplicate rows, but keeps one?

I've looked on SO and Google for answers but none seem to work/fit my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primary key `` (`id`) `` added - so

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM patch t1
JOIN patch t2 USING (title, version)
WHERE t1.id > t2.id
```

Answer (score 2):

This answers the original version of the question.

The simplest method in this case is to empty the table and rebuild it:

```
create table temp_t as
    select distinct title_id, version
    from t;

truncate table t;   -- back it up first!

insert into t (title_id, version)
    select title_id, version
    from temp_t;
```

An alternative method is to add an auto-incremented primary key column and then use that for deletion:

```
alter table t add column id int auto_increment primary key;

delete t
from t left join
     (select title, version, min(id) as min_id
      from t
      group by title, version
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.min_id
where tt.min_id is null;

alter table t drop column id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d05e45d997bc3250aa4a72b09f6a1e4e) is a db<>fiddle with this version.

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, Gordon. Is it possible to make a query that doesn't create a different table/rebuilds a table?

Comment: @AppelFlap There is no info in your table which allows to distinguish separate records which are duplicates. Maybe you have simplified the real structure, and some primary index exists?

Comment: @Akina Do you mean if there's a autoincrement id? If yes, I've modified my question to include it.

Comment: @AppelFlap Any primary or unique index - either synthetic or natural.

Comment: @AppelFlap . . .(1) I consider it rude to change a question so that existing answers are invalidated.  (2) The second solution proposed is essentially the same as the other answer, except it explicitly adds the id in.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I was requested information by Akina, so I provided that in the question. I'm sorry if you consider this rude. The reason why I accepted Akina's answer is because their answer is very easy to understand, which could be useful for other people having the same problem as me (future reference). I do however appreciate your answer and effort to help me out, it's very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You must delete all the rows with `id`s different than than the minimum `id`s for each combination of `titleid` and `version`:

```
delete from patch
where id not in (
  select t.id from (
    select min(id) id
    from patch
    group by titleid, version
  ) t  
);
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/65SvHgezNykx1ojW3tQFM3/0).
Results:

```
| id  | titleid | version |
| --- | ------- | ------- |
| 1   | TEST1   | 1.6     |
| 5   | TEST55  | 1.55    |
| 6   | TEST88  | 1.85    |
| 7   | TEST56  | 1.6     |
```